# Angular JS, add filter condition to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this:

```
<td ng-repeat="link in fund.pdfLinks track by $index" class="fundLitCmpnt-linkWrap"><a class="fundLitCmpnt-link" target="_blank" href="{{link.url}}"><i class="sprite pdfIcon"></i></a></td>
```

I would like to add a filter to the ng-repeat so if `link.url` is a specific string(/myfolder/mypage.aspx). I would like to not show that anchor tag.

I have tried this:

```
<td ng-repeat="link in fund.pdfLinks track by $index | filter:link.url'!=/myfolder/mypage.aspx'}" class="fundLitCmpnt-linkWrap"><a class="fundLitCmpnt-link" target="_blank" href="{{link.url}}"><i class="sprite pdfIcon"></i></a></td>
```

How do I compare `link.url` with a specific string? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with ng-hide.

it will hide the current element if link url mathces the string

```
<td ng-repeat="link in fund.pdfLinks track by $index"
 ng-hide="link.url=='/myfolder/mypage.aspx'"
 class="fundLitCmpnt-linkWrap">
<a class="fundLitCmpnt-link" target="_blank" href="{{link.url}}">
<i class="sprite pdfIcon"></i>
</a>
</td>
```

If you want to hide the inside elements also, you can use ng-hide individually or can use span/div like

```
<td ng-repeat="link in fund.pdfLinks track by $index"

 class="fundLitCmpnt-linkWrap">
   <div ng-hide="link.url=='/myfolder/mypage.aspx'">
      <a class="fundLitCmpnt-link" target="_blank" href="{{link.url}}">
       <i class="sprite pdfIcon"></i>
      </a>
 </div>
</td>
```

Comment: This is working, but it is hiding the entire td element, which is messing my table layout....I just want to hide all that is inside of the td?

Answer (score 2):

In your case preferable way is using ng-hide or ng-if but you can also acheive it by filters

```
angular.module('YourModule').filter('customFl',function(url){
return url !='your_url'
})

<td ng-repeat="link in fund.pdfLinks track by $index | customFl' " class="fundLitCmpnt-linkWrap"><a class="fundLitCmpnt-link" target="_blank" href="{{link.url}}"><i class="sprite pdfIcon"></i></a></td>
```

Happy Helping!